# Example of Using AJAX Oauth call from Suitelet to call a restlet

Tags: ajax, oauth, netsuite

I have been trying this for quite some time and with no avail. Would someone point me to the right direction.

I have a simple suitelet
the suitelet dumps a html in the response by reading a file
The html has a button. On ajax call of that button, a restlet gets called and a request is sent.

This is working great with Login and internal calls. However, I want the suitelet to be available without login and also the restlet.

When I do that, I get CORS error and using jsonp when I relsolve that, I get 401 Unauthorized

Tried Outh and NLAuth, no avail.

Will really appreciate any help or pointers.

Comment: Restlets will never be available without login and you cannot set CORS headers directly in Netsuite. What is the context of the call? Is it a website or within the NS GUI?

Comment: Yeah we have a suitelet that I want externally available with HTML dumped in it. Just want NS to host it.

Answer (score 0):

If the info isn't sensitive you can call the suitelet from the domain of your website. If you have enabled https on the site then that'll just work

e.g. https://forms.na3.netsuite.com/app/site... becomes http://example.com/app/site...

If you are using SCA then you can also just do this by calling a .ss service function. The nice thing about that is that you can set the role on the .ss file and have better control of your resources without just making the customer center role capable of seeing everything. Same issue with https though.

If the info is sensitive you can get around the issue on most browsers by embedding an iframe at the https:// forms etc and using the onMessage operation to transfer info from the non-secure to the secure. (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

It's certainly possible to call a RESTlet from a Suitelet but it sounds like your issue is more how to call the Suitelet securely.

Comment: irrespective I see that I have to host the suitelet on a non-NS server - right? This is a huge issue because I now have to worry about availability of my server. I think I am going the suitelet way and have the user login to access my suitelet and that works fine calling restlet. The login screen will appear and when the user logs in they will see the suitelet (and it calls the restlet, no auth is needed)

Comment: Not on a non-NS server. You have not described the context in which you want the suitelet to run. My point  was that if you are calling the suitelet from your NS hosted website then you can use that domain to avoid CORS issues